# Query for table column names returns no results to the calling code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, enterprise-library

I have a stored procedure query that I want to return the details of columns within a specific table.  When I run the sp in Sql server managements studio I get results returned.  The problem is when I try to execute the query from C# code.  There are no exceptions thrown and the relevant persmissions are granted to execute the procedure in the database but no results are returned to the code.  I'm using the enterprise application block version 3.1.

This is my query

```
    SELECT   SysObjects.[Name] as TableName,
             SysColumns.[Name] as ColumnName,
             SysTypes.[Name] As DataType,
             SysColumns.[Length] As Length
    FROM    SysObjects INNER JOIN SysColumns   ON SysObjects.[Id] = SysColumns.[Id]
    INNER JOIN SysTypes  ON SysTypes.[xtype] = SysColumns.[xtype]
    WHERE  SysObjects.[type] = 'U'
        AND SysObjects.[Name] = 'MyTableName'
    ORDER BY  SysObjects.[Name]
```

C# Calling code

```
using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("StoredProcedureName"))
{
    DataSet data = new DataSet();

    db.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, data, "MyTableName");
    if (data.Tables.Count > 0 && data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // Do stuff with the returned data
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the C#-code where you call your sql-statement?

Comment: your SQL works, the problem is the C# program

Comment: If this is using the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block (as it seems, maybe version 3.1?) you should update the question to include that and tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the C# issue, but you should consider changing your query to use the data-abstraction layer provided by Microsoft. The use of the SYSOBJECTS references is not guaranteed to be the same between SQL Versions.

Instead I'd use this:

```
--
-- for a specific tables columns
--
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

--
-- For all the user tables in the current database..
--
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='MyTableName'
```